# как отправить изображение, ботом телеграмма telebot

Tags: python, telebot, img

как отправить изображение ботом телеграмма на телеботе?.

Answer (score 0):

`bot.send_document(message.chat.id,'url')`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]